Power BI Connection to GCP Authorized Source with RLS
Objective: I would like to establish a connection between Power BI and GCP authorized source to take advantage of the existing RLS configured within GCP. The goal is to use the RLS defined in the GCP source without duplicating it in Power BI, ensuring that any updates or changes in the GCP RLS logic (such as adding new dimensions) are automatically reflected in Power BI.
Key Requirements:

DirectQuery Connection:


The connection between Power BI and BigQuery (GCP) should be set up using DirectQuery mode.
The solution should capture and use the context of the currently logged-in Power BI user, ensuring that the RLS defined in GCP is correctly applied.


Authentication Method:


The connection must use personal credentials rather than a service account.
A specific option, "Report viewers can only access this data source with their own Power BI identities using DirectQuery," must be enabled to ensure that the user context is preserved.

Issue Encountered: During the process of establishing the DirectQuery connection, the required option ("Report viewers can only access this data source with their own Power BI identities using DirectQuery") does not appear.
